# Java: How can I detect monitor refresh rate on Linux?

Tags: java, linux

Is there any way to detect a monitor's current refresh rate using Java on Linux?

I currently have 2 monitors connected, primary being 240 Hz and secondary being 60 Hz.
I have tried using the following snippet [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/GettingtheCurrentScreenRefreshRateandNumberofColors.htm). On Windows it successfully gets these values, however on Linux it first returns 50, followed by 0.

Do I have to rely on underlying system tools, and if so, are there any that a given Linux system is most likely to have, E.G. `xrandr`?

I am using openjdk-1.8.0_252